# entityQuery with multivalue date field

Tags: 8, database, datetime

Is there way to use `entityQuery` in order to select nodes with multiple value date field. For example we have a content type `event` with a field `field_event_date` which may contain unlimited number of dates. Is there any way to select all `event` nodes that occur on a certain day? E.g. we have `field_event_date` equals to

`[
  10.09.2018
  11.09.2018
  13.09.2018
]`

the node with this field should be returned for when "10.09.2018", "11.09.2018", "13.09.2018" is passed, and omitted for any other date (including "12.09.2018).

Answer (score 1):

- Try this Out:

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', NodeInterface::PUBLISHED)
    ->condition('type', 'event')
    ->condition('field_event_date', ['10.09.2018', '11.09.2018', '13.09.2018' ], 'IN')
    ->range(0, 10);

  $result = $query->execute();
```